# Android Studio Runtime Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. I tried to execute "Hello World!" code using android nougat 7.1.1 and got this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.myfirstapp.myapplication, PID: 5369
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myfirstapp.myapplication/com.myfirstapp.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at com.myfirstapp.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>   Application terminated.

What should I do?

[image: Error]

Comment: Show your code too. It seems you are calling an nonexistent button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign the Fab from your xml layout to your Fab in java reference. It is saying you are trying to set an OnClickListener to an object that has no value yet or a "null" value.

android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at